# Get filesystem location of a contact's image

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am making an app for Android. It creates a phonebook. I use a ListView custom to show contacts informations. The image of a single contact is shown by an ImageView and a bitmap created with the following path:

`/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20140114_113323.jpg`

There is a function in my App to import a contact from the default Android phonebook. When I take the image URI from the contact I have the following:

`content://com.android.contacts/contacts/2681`

My question is: how can I find the real path of the contact image if I only have this URI?

Comment: **In ENGLISH, please!!**

Comment: please add the code block you have tried so far

Comment: I use many classes in this App, I can not post the code. I only need a method or something to replace:
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/2681
in something like:
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20140114_113323.jpg